# ERROR: Failed to resolve: android.support:support.v7:29.0.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android studio. I am facing a problem with the coding part. While running the code it shows an error.
Thw gradle part is shown below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fallprediction"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'android.support:support.v7:29.0.2'
}
```

The error is 
ERROR: Failed to resolve: android.support:support.v7:29.0.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Please help me to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

Convert this into androidx or remove this dependency   implementation 'android.support:support.v7:29.0.2